# Replacing a string of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a string passed to stored procedure, 
`@detailsparameter= "Id=1,2,3,4,UserId=1,2, FirstName=Sam,LastName=Harry,Age=22, Organization=Bestbuy,Apple"`

I need to replace the comma with ";" in SQL stored procedure after finding a pattern as below

```
@detailsparameter= "Id=1,2,3,4;UserId=1,2; FirstName=Sam;LastName=Harry;Age=22;Organization=Bestbuy,Apple"`
```

Comment: @GMB commas followed by word and "=" should be replaced with ";"

Comment: 1. What rdbms are you working with? string manipulation functions is very vendor-specific. 2. Why are you messing around with delimited strings in the first place?

Comment: This looks extremely troublesome. Is there any reason that you aren't passing the individual parameters to the stored procedure?

Comment: because it is passed as list with mutiple parameters. I made it work of Entitiy Framework using Regex.replace

Answer (score 0):

I would just do this under sql server:

```
set @detailsparameter = replace(@detailsparameter, ',FirstName','; FirstName')
set @detailsparameter = replace(@detailsparameter, ',LastName','; LastName')
set @detailsparameter = replace(@detailsparameter, ',UserId','; UserId')
set @detailsparameter = replace(@detailsparameter, ',Age','; Age')
set @detailsparameter = replace(@detailsparameter, ',Organization','; Organization')
```